# django auth - has_perm returns True while list of permissions is empty

Tags: django-authentication

I'm wondering why this code section prints out the following:

```
print "request.user.has_perm('bug_tracking.is_developer'): " + str(request.user.has_perm('bug_tracking.is_developer'))
                    print request.user.get_all_permissions()

request.user.has_perm('bug_tracking.is_developer'): True
set([])
```

I would expect that request.user.has_perm('bug_tracking.is_developer') returns false if the list of all permissions is empty!?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

huups...was a super user ;-)

Superuser status
Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that if you have a method `has_perm` in you User model, the authentication backends' `has_perm` methods will not called ever.